# Measure Maximum Fontsize for a control

Tags: wpf

Lets say I have 5 Textblocks on screen each with the same size.

I also have 5 items to display (of varying length)

- 10
- 100
- 1111
- 99
- 9192

Is there a way with WPF to calculate the largest FontSize usable for the textblocks so that all the Text will fit in it's respective textblock, but so that all the fontsizes are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a viewbox

```
        <Viewbox>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="1111"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>
```

then everything inside the viewbox will scale to fit the size available for the viewbox, regardless of the font size.